# array must be of constant range error

Tags: verilog, compression

i have an output reg called compressed_out.base_size and delta_size are parameters.  if the enable[l] = 0, I need the base_size bits in sub_out to be written to  compressed_out. if enable[l]=1, only delta_size number of bits from sub_out is to be taken to compressed_out. how can we give correct ranges in the body of if else statement to select bits of compressed_out. 
my code is not correct, please help me to solve the issue.

```
wire [base_size - 1:0 ]sub_out[n-2:0];
.
.
for(l=0;l<n-1;l=l+1)
    begin
    if(enable[l]==0)
    compressed_output[(base_size *(l+2)-1)-:base_size] = sub_out[l];

    else
    compressed_output[(base_size - delta_size)*(l+2)-1 -:(base_size - delta_size) ] = sub_out[l][delta_size -1 :0];
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

What the error says: the size/width of the register, which comes from the expression after the `-:`, must be a constant.

You can *not* have variable width assignments. How do you want to do that in hardware?
You can use only part(s) of an existing register which means you have to start with a register big enough for the maximum size you think you will need.

---

If you tell a bit more about what you want to do and the limits we might come up with a solution. Often shift operations `<< >>` can get you a long way.

Comment: hello, i hope my question is more clear now. I want a generalised expression for the range selection of compressed_out.